# How should I name a native DLL distributed in both 32-bit and 64-bit form?

Tags: dll, win64, native-code

I have a commercial product that's a DLL (native 32-bit code), and now it's time to build a 64-bit version of it. So when installing on 64-bit Windows, the 32-bit version goes into Windows\SysWOW64, and the 64-bit version goes into... Windows\System32! (I'm biting my tongue here...)
Or the DLL(s) can be installed alongside the client application.

What should I name the 64-bit DLL?

Same name as 32-bit: Two files that do the same thing, have the same name, but are totally non-interchangeable. Isn't that a recipe for confusion and support problems?

Different names (e.g. product.dll and product64.dll): Now client applications have to know whether they are running 32-bit or 64-bit in order to reference my DLL, and there are languages where that isn't known until run-time - .NET being just one example.  And now all the statically compiled clients have to conditionalize the import declarations: IF target=WIN64 THEN import Blah from "product64.dll" ELSE import Blah from "product.dll" ENDIF

The product contains massive amounts of C code, and a large chunk of C++ - porting it to C# is not an option.

Advice?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to follow Microsoft on this, who have kept the same names for the DLLs in System32 when they went to 64-bit. On Win7/64, System32\avicap32.dll is a 64-bit DLL!

There is some potential confusion for myself & my customers, having 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs with the same name. However I think it would be worse to have all my customers have to make their code word-width sensitive. Especially the .NET developers, who can often leave their target platform set to 'AnyCPU'.

Answer (score 2):

Client applications *do not* have to "know" they are 32 bit or 64 bit. The OS automatically loads DLLs from the appropriate location because it is not possible to load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process, and it is not possible to load a 64 bit DLL into a 32 bit process.

If a 32 bit application *tries to* load something from system32, the OS will silently redirect it to the SysWow64 directory, forcing the 32 bit version to load.

By having different names, you defeat this whole mechanism. A mechanism built specifically to allow you to use the same name.

Comment: Your answer assumes that my DLLs will always be installed in the shared system folders, which is absolutely not a valid assumption.  Many (most?) of my customers prefer to install supporting DLLs for their apps alongside the app.
However! I agree (as you can see in my self-answer) that it's best not to fight city hall, so I have two absolutely non-interchangeable DLLs with identical names, and Windows offers no built-in way to tell which is which.

Comment: @Spike0xff Storing copies of libraries alongside the executable defeats the purpose of shared libraries. You should probably be static linking. If you are going to store a copy of the whole library, you might as well embed it in the executable. At least then, it drops unused portions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not prefix the dll's with an underscore ... such as **product_32.dll** and **product_64.dll**? OR indicated this by using a platform prefix - **product_x86_32.dll** and **product_x86_64.dll**? At least that will clear the confusion of the naming of the DLL... What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Some languages that call DLLs have a mechanism to adapt their names according to the calling application bitness.
For example in *LabVIEW*, the DLL name can be automatically adapted when using one of two patterns:

1. `MyDll*.dll` will translate on win32 to **MyDll32.dll** and on win64 to **MyDll64.dll**.
2. `MyDll**.dll` will translate on win32 to **MyDll.dll** and on win64 to **MyDll_64.dll** (notice the underscore).

So a suggested naming scheme for native DLL, distributed in both 32-bit and 64-bit binary form is:
|           | win32         | win64          |
|:--------- |:--------------|:---------------|
| Scheme 1  | `MyDll32.dll` | `MyDll64.dll`  |
| Scheme 2  | `MyDll.dll`   | `MyDll_64.dll` |

Having different names can be useful if both DLLs must be in the same folder - alongside the application for example.

**Note**: if you do not *need* to have different names, I agree with the [answer of doug65536](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33585559/6803759). If you install the DLLs in windows system folders (SysWOW64 and System32), you are better off using the **same name** `MyDll.dll` for both bitnesses and let Windows do its magic when needed.